# How to make a velocity(time) XYplot graph in NASA's GMAT R2022?

Tags: nasa, gmat

I'm wondering how to design a graph in NASA's GMAT (Version R2022a), which shows satellite's linear velocity on time or on altitude from primary body (Earth).
When I open the **XYplot design window** -> **Selected Y** I can't find the satellite's property - velocity, which I'm looking for.
Maybe the velocity in the **Object Properties** window has a fancy shortcut, or a strange name..?

Does anyone know, what's the velocity's name in the **Object Properties** window, or how to find it?

Comment: I'm not a GMAT user, but is there a "[state vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_state_vectors)" option? (e.g. $[\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z}, \mathbf{v_x}, \mathbf{v_y}, \mathbf{v_z}]$)

Comment: Thanks @uhoh, I've found the **state vectors** you've mentioned, in GMAT they're called VY,VX,VZ in the **Object Properties** list. Using separate VX and VY functions, the graph is kind of too complex for the task. Still would prefer a simpler, single function linear speed (I've made a mistake in my question, speed would be better than velocity in my case) graph, but that's already something. Thank you again ;)

Comment: @phil1008, that is exactly the case, I have posted as a guest and created an account later

Comment: @PIasni 1) When we use `@username` in a comment, it generates a message to that person letting them know you replied. But although we sometimes use it in question and answer posts, it has no effect there. From the main meta's [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) see [How do comment `@replies` work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) 2) there's a standard procedure to merge your two accounts see [this answer to *How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233/303080)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find the **VMAG** property in the list, which can then be linked to a coordinate system below the **Object Properties** window :)